# mysql auto-increment - reassign after a record has been deleted

Tags: php, sql, auto-increment

I'm using `auto-increment` to assign a id to every new entry in my database.
Also, i've got a php-script which is selecting 10 entrys from this database, according to the current pagenumber.
For example, if the current page is 2, the script should select every entry between id=20 and id=29.

Now, if i delete an entry, the id is lost. Therefore the script will only show 9 entrys when id28 has been deleted.

Is there a way to reassign the `auto-increment` values after e record has been deleted?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the "offset" from the LIMIT clause? `LIMIT 0, 10`, next page `LIMIT 10, 10`, next page `LIMIT 20, 10`, …

Comment: I never heard of this before. Should have studied the whole sql thing better i guess :o
Much thanks, this is great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is usually considered desirable: if entry number `28` is deleted, there will never again be an entry `28`. If someone ever tries to refer to it, they're clearly trying to refer to the one that's been deleted, and you can report an error.

If you went back and reassigned `28` to some new entry, now you have no idea whether the person meant the ***old*** `28` or the ***new*** record.

Let's take a step back and revisit what you want to do. Your goal is not to show ten entries between `20` and `30`. Your goal is to show ten entries that meet your criteria. For that, you can use the built-in `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` terms:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
OFFSET 29
LIMIT 10
```

The `OFFSET` tells MySQL where to start counting and `LIMIT` tells it how many to count. MySQL will put together the whole result set, then give you 10 entries beginning at the 30th one. That's your fourth page of results. It does not remotely matter now what IDs they happen to have.

Answer (score 3):

You should change the way you select entries for a page.

By using the LIMIT .. OFFSET clause, you will be able to select 10 entries, starting at Nth entry:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     table
ORDER BY id
LIMIT    10
OFFSET   19
```

- `LIMIT 10` means *return only 10 rows*
- `OFFSET 19` means *return rows after 19th row*

This way, it doesn't matter if some id has been removed and ids are not sequential.

Just change the OFFSET:

- Page 1 => OFFSET 0
- Page 2 => OFFSET 9
- Page 3 => OFFSET 19
- Page N => OFFSET (N-1)*10-1

Comment: That should be `LIMIT 0, 10` as this is a zero-based offset?

Answer (score 1):

Your question suggests a query like

```
SELECT columns FROM table WHERE id BETWEEN 20 AND 29;
```

or less elegant

```
SELECT columns FROM table WHERE id >= 20 AND id <= 29;
```

If so, I suggest you read up on the [LIMIT clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) and do somethong along the lines of

```
SELECT columns FROM table ORDER BY id LIMIT 20, 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can but you shouldn't. If id=29 exists are you reset the auto-increment to 28, then there will be problems when auto-increment wants to use id=29 but the record already exists.

You'd be better off writing a query like so:

```
select * from table order by ID LIMIT n,10;
```

Where n is the page number*10

Answer (score 1):

Reassign auto-increment values it's bad practice, because id, may used in relation with other tables.Use offset / limit construction, and forget about reassign auto-increment :)

Answer (score 1):

As a direct answer to your question (auto_increment), you can change its value with the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table` AUTO_INCREMENT = 200
```

The next created item would have its next AI collumn value set to 200. This is useful in some cases, although I agree you would be better off using the LIMIT offsets.